# Count rows in table that are the same in a sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a table  that looks like this

```
 +----+------------+------+
 | ID | Session_ID | Type |
 +----+------------+------+
 |  1 |          1 |    2 |
 |  2 |          1 |    4 |
 |  3 |          1 |    2 |
 |  4 |          2 |    2 |
 |  5 |          2 |    2 |
 |  6 |          3 |    2 |
 |  7 |          3 |    1 |
 +----+------------+------+
```

And I would like to count all occurences of a `type` that are in a sequence.

Output look some how like this:

```
 +------------+------+-----+
 | Session_ID | Type | cnt |
 +------------+------+-----+
 |          1 |    2 |   1 |
 |          1 |    4 |   1 |
 |          1 |    2 |   1 |
 |          2 |    2 |   2 |
 |          3 |    2 |   1 |
 |          3 |    1 |   1 |
 +------------+------+-----+
```

A simple `group by` like

```
SELECT session_id, type, COUNT(type)
FROM table
GROUP BY session_id, type
```

doesn't work, since I need to group only rows that are "touching".

Is this possible with a merge sql-select or will I need some sort of coding. Stored Procedure or Application side coding?

**UPDATE** Sequence:
If the following row has the same `type`, it should be counted (ordered by `ID`).

to determine the sequence the `ID` is the key with the `session_ID`, since I just want to group rows with the same `session_ID`.

So if there are 3 rows is in one session

- row with the ID 1 has type 1,
- and the second row has type 1
- and row 3 has type 2

**Input:**

```
 +----+------------+------+
 | ID | Session_ID | Type |
 +----+------------+------+
 |  1 |          1 |    1 |
 |  2 |          1 |    1 |
 |  3 |          1 |    2 |
 +----+------------+------+
```

The squence is Row 1 to Row 2. This three row should output

**Output:**

```
 +------------+------+-------+
 | Session_ID | Type | count |
 +------------+------+-------+
 |          1 |    1 |     2 |
 |          3 |    2 |     1 |
 +------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: define `sequence`. What is in a sequence? Also, what `dbms` are you using? `SQL` is just a language.

Comment: sequence is like as in the example table 1,2,3,... ordered by ID. (will update the question, to make it more clear). MSSQL . I will update the tags.

Comment: But what sequence? Your example table has `2,2,2` yet the corresponding counts are `1,2,1`???? You mention `type`, yet your comment mentions `ID`????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a difference of `id` and `row_number()` to identify the gaps and then perform your count

```
;with cte as
(
Select *, id - row_number() over (partition by session_id,type order by id) as grp 
from table
)
select session_id,type,count(*) as cnt
from cte
group by session_id,type,grp 
order by max(id)
```

Comment: @winner_joiner . . . This answer is assuming that `id` is consecutive and has no gaps.  This generally cannot be guaranteed in a database.